# Induced short exact sequence of symmetry product

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am reading Huybrechts’s book: The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves. In Section 1.4, he says following things:

Let $k$ be  algebraically closed and of characteristic 0. Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer and $V$ a $k-$ vector space of dimension $n+1$. Let $\mathbb{P}(V)$ be the associated projective vector space and $\Omega:=\Omega_{\mathbb{P}(V)}$ be the cotangent bundle. Then we have the Euler sequence $$0\to \Omega(1)\to V\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)\to 0 $$.
These things are correct. But then he says symmetrizing the sequence, we get exact sequences:

$$0\to S^{d}(\Omega(1))\to S^{d}(V)\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}\to S^{d-1}V\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)\to 0$$

He also says that the characteristic of $k$ be zero is necassary for the surjectivity.

I am very confused. As I know, for any exact sequence
$$0\to M \to N \to P\to 0$$
We always have $$M\otimes S^{d-1}(N)\to S^{d}(N)\to S^{d}(P)\to 0$$

I am not sure what Huybrechts uses here. Why we can get the exact sequence? Also why $\mathrm{char}(k)=0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In characteristic zero the exact sequence you wrote is a part of the long exact sequence
$$
0 \to
\wedge^m(M) \otimes S^{d-m}(N) \to \dots \to
\wedge^2(M) \otimes S^{d-2}(N) \to 
M \otimes S^{d-1}(N) \to S^d(N) \to S^d(P) \to 0,
$$
but if $M$ is an invertible sheaf, it reduces to the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to M \otimes S^{d-1}(N) \to S^d(N) \to S^d(P) \to 0.
$$
And the dual construction applied to the Euler sequence gives what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you tell me where I could find such exact sequence and why do we need characteristic zero? Could you give me the reference?

Comment: I think you can find all this in the book Weyman, Jerzy "Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies", Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, 149.